# Value? is wrong when passed by reference

Tags: c++, reference

I'm not very proficient in c++ so when I did the program, I first made it in Java so that I could better understand and help translate that over to c++
Here is the code:

Odometer.h

```
    class Odometer
    {
    public:
     Odometer();
     int traveled(int mils);
     void report();
    private:
     int miles;
    };
```

Odometer class:

```
    #include "Odometer.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    Odometer::Odometer(){ //just added
    miles = 0; //initializing
    }
    int Odometer::traveled(int mils){
    miles = miles + mils;
    return miles;
    }
    void Odometer::report(){
    int limit = 999999;
    if (miles < limit){
        cout << miles;
        }
    else{
        miles = 0;
    }
    }
```

FuelGauge.h

```
    class FuelGauge{
     public:
      FuelGauge();
      int add(int gallons);
      void report();
      void decrement(int gallons);
     private:
      int gallons;
     };
```

FuelGauge class

```
#include "FuelGauge.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

FuelGauge::FuelGauge(){ //just added 
gallons = 0;
}
int FuelGauge::add(int gals){
    gallons = gallons + gals;
    return gallons;
    }
void FuelGauge::report(){
    cout << gallons << endl;
    }
void FuelGauge::decrement(int galls){
    gallons = gallons - galls;
    }
```

CarInfoMain class

```
#include "FuelGauge.h"
#include "Odometer.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    FuelGauge g;
    Odometer m;
    int gallons;
    int miles;

    cout << "How many gallons do you want to start with in the car? " << endl;
    cin >> gallons;
    g.add(gallons);
    cout << "How far did you travel? " << endl;
    cin >> miles;
    g.decrement(miles / 24);
    cout << "Current Gallons now: " << endl;
    g.report(); //<--- this is where it doesn't return it right
    /*cout << "Odometer: " << endl;
    m.report();*/
}
```

Sample run:

> Gallons started with? 14
>
> Miles traveled? 150
>
> Current gallons now: 1470880840 //usually a large number of this size,
>   sometimes //with a minus in the front, e.g -574807128

I don't know why it won't work. Thanks

Comment: Where do you initialise FuelGuage::gallons to 0 ? You do not show any constructor to do this.

Comment: sorry, I don't know what you mean. Are you saying that I should have initialized gallons to 0 in the FuelGauge.h? And I thought that it would be 0 by default.

Comment: why would it be 0 by default ? You do not show your constructor, you create your object on the stack.

Comment: Well my mistake. But do you mean just set gallons to 0 to start with?

Comment: Do you have a constructor ? You do not show all of your code so I have to assume what is happening from partial information. You have a function called add() which accumulates. What is the initial value of the accumulator. Either initialise the accumulator in the constructor, have a set/reset method to reset the accumulator, or do both.

Comment: okay, I'll try to do add those right now

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the answer. It makes it confusing for anyone coming to the question later.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't know. I was just trying to put as much Info out there, so is the code right then? because when I try to link the .o files, the linux says an error of "undefined reference to Odometer::Odometer()"

Answer (score 1):

In c++ local variables have garbage values/(what ever was in the memory cell before it was allocated for your variable) by default.

So when you do miles = miles + mils
You are adding mile to some garbage value
Just initializing miles and gallons with 0 will fix it.

int miles = 0;
int gallons = 0;

Comment: So do I just initialize those in their respective classes?
like in FuelGauge class, int gallons = 0;?

Comment: Yes, it's recommended to do so using a constructor.

Comment: Okay. I think I did that. but then I got "undefined reference to Odometer::Odometer();"..

Comment: since you do not have a constructor, the compiler cannot find it.

Comment: I just edited my code above, it now has the constructor in it.
in my headers, it has the constructor as "Odometer();"
I thought I was doing it right but still the same error of undefined reference

Comment: perhaps if you posted the headers as well, so we do not have to imagine what they look like.

Comment: How many gallons do you want to start with in the car? 
14
How far did you travel? 
150
Current Gallons now: 
8

Comment: really? because it compiles fine but the linking fails in the linux. And yea, that's what the output should be like